# Channel Element type too large Golang

Tags: arrays, matrix, go, channel, goroutine

I'm writing a program that works with matrixes in parallel.

My matrixes are created using a constant `n`.

```
const n = 10
```

The channels are created with the following code:

```
a := make(chan [n][n]int)
```

This works fine for anything under a value of around `12` for `n` however anything greater and the following error is given:

```
channel element type too large (>64kB)
```

Looking at tutorials etc, and it seem buffered channels may be the way to solve this but I tried doing this with the following code and the same error was given:

```
a := make(chan [n][n]int, 1000)
```

Am I using buffered channels correctly or are they not the way to solve this issue? Any tips on how I can move forward with this greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Following on from the answer given and comments I'm now trying to create a global matrix which is blank and go routines can write to.

```
const n int = 1024

blank [n][n]int
```

I'm unsure how it could be declared globally and have attempted the above to solve this. Does it need initialising globally? Everything I seem to try gives errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The channel being buffered or not has nothing to do with this, the error is not with the space for storing elements but with the size of a single element. The size limit of the channel's element type is an implementation detail / restriction, you can't do anything about that.

And if you try to use an element type violating this, that signals you're doing something wrong (something you shouldn't do). Whenever you send a value on a channel, the value will be copied. So sending >64KB values on a channel is not really efficient.

Instead choose an element type which is small. The choice requiring the least change would be to use a pointer to your type: `*[n][n]int`.

```
a := make(chan *[n][n]int)
```

Then of course you have to send pointers on the channel, and you'll receive pointers from it, e.g.:

```
const n = 132
a := make(chan *[n][n]int)

go func() {
    var v [n][n]int
    a <- &v // Sending a pointer
}()

v2 := <-a
fmt.Println(v2)  // It's a pointer
fmt.Println(*v2) // It's an array value
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wMs7y7vJQ0).

You should also keep in mind that since now we're sending / receiving pointers on the channel, it will point to the same array value, and thus modifying the pointed value will modify the same array whose address we sent on the channel. If this is unwanted, make a copy before sending, and send the address of the copy:

```
var v [n][n]int
// Making a copy:
v2 := v
a <- &v2 // Sending address of the copy
```

You should also consider working with [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) instead of [arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types).

**Edit:**

Declaring a global array is as easy as this:

```
var result [n][n]int
```

(It must be outside of other blocks, in the file scope.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, would it make sense for me to create a struct called matrix and use that rather than the [n][n]int every time?

Comment: @benjano That wouldn't change anything, the size of a struct type cannot be less than the sum of the size of all its field types.

Comment: If I wanted to perform calculations on the matrices in parallel, would I want a global variable which contains a blank matrix of the same size which can then be saved to?

Comment: @benjano That depends on the nature of your calculations. If calculations read/write the same elements, access must be synchronized. If calculations only read the elements, no synchronization is needed, and you don't even need channels.

Comment: I'm generating two random matrices, I'm then adding them together. Currently my program splits the matrices in half and passes the halves into two separate goroutines which are then worked on concurrently. These two halves are then passed out and reconstructed. However due to the need for the reconstruction at the end it's a lot slower than the sequential version. I want to be able to write and save to another matrix which will give the result.

Comment: @benjano Generating and adding 2 small matrices, you might not even see performance improvements, as synchronization and work distribution also has its overhead. Having said that, the work of generating and adding 2 matrices can be split without actually splitting the matrices, as adding matrices simply means adding the elements at the same index (an element will have no effect in the result on elements having different indices).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if splitting was the correct word. I'm limiting the area each goroutine can work within the two matrixes so each goroutine will complete the maths for one section. I'm just unsure how to save to a resultMatrix which all goroutines can write too

Comment: @benjano You can have a global array for that, just make sure different goroutines are not writing the same area of it.

Comment: I've added a little more to my question relating to this, any further tips you can give appreciated.

Comment: @benjano See edited answer how to create a global variable.